# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Collection' not found in [$path]test.php:10

Tags: mongodb, php-7.2

I have installed the driver of mongo db using pecl and also edit the **php.ini** file by adding **extension="mongodb.so"** .
When I trying to connect with the database by the following code:

```
<?php
if($m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost"))
     echo "Connecting Successfully";
$users = $m->TaskLogger->user->find();
var_dump($users);
?>
```

If shows the output like that.:
[Connection is succefull yet not able to connect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhoQv.png)

I am using xampp 7.2.5 and php version 7.2.5.
In phpinfo page. mongodb extension is added..

Please help me in that issue...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After the php module installation you need to use the MongoDB Driver by using composer

Follow this link 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php

1.- Install composer
2.- Install the dependency

```
composer require mongodb/mongodb
```

3.- And finally add the autoloader in your script, by adding composer autoloader

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // include Composer's autoloader
$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost")
```